# Why won't my horse show hearts when tamed?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have ridden this horse a lot and have stopped getting thrown off, but I never got any hearts. Even Golden Apples and Golden Carrots don't give me hearts like the Minecraft wiki says they will when fed to a tamed horse. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you playing Survival or Creative? If memory serves me, I don't think the hearts appear in Creative Mode.

Comment: Also, do you have your particles turned on?  If they're off (for instance, if you don't want to listen to rain), then you won't see the hearts.

Comment: Definitely not  a duplicate. Read the question carefully.

Comment: I am playing in creative that's must be why. And I don't Have the rain going It lags my game but thanks. I'll try it in Survival. thank you. I really thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Hearts may not appear if your particle count is set to none in the graphics settings. Set it to a higher setting and viola! hearts to your heart's content.

Comment: If that worked for you, I'd appreciate it if you checked it as the correct answer! It even gives you some reputation if you do so!

Answer (score 2):

If you can get on and ride a horse without being thrown off, you have almost certainly tamed it. The hearts may have appeared without you noticing, or may not have appeared due to a graphics issue. See if you can saddle this horse, and maybe try taming another.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in your video settings you don't have minimal particles. To make sure you don't miss the hearts, make sure all particles are on.

Answer (score -1):

If your horse stops bucking you off but doesn't show the hearts, then I believe that you still tamed it, and it's just a display error.